# ElasticSearch 30.5GB Heap Size Restriction

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

We use ES to store around 2.5TB of data. We have 12 primary shards and 2 replica shards.
We are currently load testing ES and I read the following article
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html

This article states 2 important things. First allocate 50% of Memory to Lucene and Second Don't cross 30.5GB limit for heap space.

I don't clearly understand the 30.5GB limit. I understand that if I am to set 40GB over 30.5 GB i will loose more than i gain(because of compressed pointers) but say if i have hardware of around 250GB RAM what are the reasons that i should only allocate 30.5GB and not 120GB for heap. Won't i start seeing gains after 70-80GB heap setting over 30.5 GB heap. Can somebody list down all the reasons?

Comment: If your node will need to run garbage collection (Java) to clear up heap memory (by default, old GC is triggered when 75% of heap is being used), clearing and checking 75%*120GB=90GB will definitely take more time than checking and clearing 75%*30.5GB=22.87GB. When old GC runs, the node is frozen, no threads are doing anything. So, from outside, your node is not there. With Elasticsearch, if one node is not ping-able for 1.5 minutes is considered out of the cluster. If this happens, you will see a lot of network activity (moving shards around) and a significant performance decrease.

Comment: From the article you linked, they advise to leave 50% of the memory to Lucene, but **only because** they are talking about a machine with 64GB RAM. If you have a 120GB beast, the 30.5 GB limit still applies to ES, but Lucene will be free to take on more than 50% (i.e. 60GB), i.e. `Lucene will happily gobble up whatever is left over.`

Comment: Yep. Question was focussed towards heap space only. Andrei is GC run the only reason apart to not increase the cluster HEAP to around 80GB? Are there any other factors?

Comment: Except the fact that you "lose" (or better said the memory management is not efficient) some memory, a GC that runs too long I think it's the only reason.